How to check string contents within a LINQ database query
In my LINQ query I want to check that a numeric string is followed by only non-numeric characters. In regex, it would look something like this: ^[0-9]+[^0-9]*$
However, I've discovered that LINQ can't translate regex.
I've also tried doing the following:
List<char> numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
var queryableNumbers = numbers.AsQueryable();

from ...
where
...
   && row.content.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchTerm)
   && !queryableNumbers.Any(number => row.content.Substring(searchTerm.Length).Contains(number))
...

Which also doesn't work because LINQ can't translate it for whatever reason. The line !queryableNumbers.Any(number => row.content.Substring(searchTerm.Length).Contains(number)) is the problem.
I've done my best to test all the components in isolation (Contains(), Any(), and Substring()) and it seems that as soon as I put Contains() inside the Any(), it fails.
All I can think to do is to keep the first line of the where block, and move the logic of the second line out of the LINQ query and into an extra loop to filter my results. In other words:

Use LINQ to get data that satisfies ^[0-9]+
Filter via a for-loop or some other option to ensure ^[0-9]+[^0-9]*$ is satisfied

I'd like to avoid an extra loop if possible. At this point I'm stuck. Does anyone have any suggestions for other ways to approach this issue.

Maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-8.0 ?

Which version of EF and which data provider?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm using EF Core 8 with SQL

Only thing I can think of is to first limit query with LIKE operator and look only for string that start with number, then in C# code, when query is fetched, filer further the results:
// Get entities which have the field starting with digit.
// [0-9]%" means match one digit and rest is arbitrary.
var semiFiltered = databaseContext.Entities
    .Where(x => DbFunctions.Like(x.SemiNumericField, "[0-9]%")
    .ToArray();

// Here we use Regex to do the rest
var filtered = semiFiltered
    .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.SemiNumericField, "^[0-9]+[^0-9]*$"))
    .ToArray();


Thanks Michał. I like the idea of using regex for the second query.

Just to be clear - first filtering is producing a query to database. Second call operates only on data already fetched from database and further filters it.

Thanks yes I did consider this towards the end of my question, but I wanted to avoid an extra parse over the data. Not the end of the world though since in my case the first check should do the vast majority of the filtering. Thanks again for the recommendation.

Marked as accepted answer because the solution was concise and performance was good.

@Jye not really the alternative you were looking for. It's what you wanted to avoid.

@GertArnold that's true but it was simple and didn't hurt performance too much. Regarding your answer, I wasn't sure if it would handle a string starting with a multi-digit number. E.g. "200a" should be accepted. Maybe I'm not reading it correctly though. That said, the existence of the Like function is useful information so thanks for that.

If a string starts with a number and the rest is not a number, it means that the substring starting at index 1 does not contain a number:
Data.Where(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.StringProp, "[0-9]%") 
    && !EF.Functions.Like(t.StringProp.Substring(1,99999), "%[0-9]%"))


Assuming this is EF core, please add a tag for the version used.
